# .NET error message when running a process more than once

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a strange error message that a data table does not include a field I am referencing (setting) when running my WinForms c# app either in Visual Studio or the executable within the \bin\release directory.

I know the field is there, and I only get the error message when I run the process that uses the datatable objects more than once.

When I click continue (in the executable) the application continues with no problems and does what it should be doing.

Here is a code snippet:

```
dtCreditCases.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (task_creditcases item in creditCases)
    {    

        DataRow drCases = dtCreditCases.NewRow();

        // Then add the new row to the collection.
        drCases["Case ID"] = item.c_Id;
        drCases["Case Number"] = item.c_Name; 
        drCases["Case Topic"] = "Credit Case";
        drCases["Case SubTopic"] = "Credit Case";
        drCases["Account Number"] = item.c_EquationCustomerNumber
```

the code stops executing on the line `drCases["Case Number"] = item.c_Name;` with the message **{"Column 'Case ID' does not belong to table ."}**.

The *inner Exception*  is null.

Here is the exeception detail:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code   Message=Column
>   'Case ID' does not belong to table .   Source=System.Data
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
>          at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(String columnName, Object value)
>          at SFDetachifier.SFDetachifier.bgProcessing_Production_ProgressChanged(Object
>   sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Dev\SFDetachifier_2013\SFDetachifier\SFDetachifier.cs:line 1304
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ProgressReporter(Object arg)
>   InnerException:

I know that the datatable is not the problem, there must be something happening elsewhere, and I am wondering if it is because the datatable is being re-used.

Should I explicitly call dispose on all objects when my process has completed?

Comment: you could use them inside using(...) clauses ...

Comment: include all IDsiposable elemnets inside using it will take care of disposing.

Comment: you can post the original rext of error here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't underdtand what you mean by 'include all iDisposable elements inside using it' - could you show me an example please?

Comment: @Vasili Ruzov: I'll do that

Comment: @Philip using(new IDisposableClass()) {
                Log.Write("Some stuff inside the context.");
                throw new Exception();
            }

Comment: @Philip. thanks for exception. are you sure that you have column "case id"? did it work in past?

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov: I am absolutely certain as the first time I run the process there are no errors and it works perfectly, it's only when I change the search dates and click the execute button to run the same process with different search criteria that this error happens

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov: should I be disposing of the background worker after each run?

Comment: @Philip, if class has Dispose method You'd better dispose it. I'm not sure that this is the problem, but it's good style.

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid you have done some changes to dtCreditCases.Columns before using the table the second time. the reason the program does what it should do is that you may put the code section in a 'try/catch' (just guess).

another reason for this issue is that the data table is shared by 2 threads in a multithread program.